# OOP Best practice on providing conveniece methods

Tags: vba, oop

I am writing a Factory Class that should allow for multiple ways to instantiate an object. Basically to create object it is posible to provide either perameters A and B or just a singleAB parameter( truth is that AB is just combination of A and B with "->" as delimiter). So my questionS are:

Is this even a good idea to provide multiple ways of instatiating and object?
If so is it better to get it done in one or multiple methods?
Is this a situation that requires use of separate concrete and abstract factories?

As you may have figured out already I am still figuring out OOP concepts.

I don't think tha tthis should matter but I am coding in VBA, but I got a gut felling that such practices should be independent of language you are using(please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: This is not really well-suited to Stack Overflow, and there's no likely definitive answer to it.  Having said that: 1) I don't see why you should *not* use a Factory class, although that's not something you'd typically use in VBA (I would be inclined just to use a regular function to return an instance of the object)  2) I would use two distinct methods if you have two distinct ways to instantiate your object 3) There is no answer to that question since "requires" is pretty subjective.

Comment: Hint: export the factory class module, open it in Notepad and set the `VB_Attribute_PredeclaredId` to `True`. Then the class will behave as a "static class" and won't need to be instantiated, which is great for factories. COM loves factories. Depending on your specific code, abstract factories might be slightly overkill for VBA, since polymorphism/inheritance is quite limited despite the possibility of implementing interfaces.

Comment: Also if you have a working VBA abstract factory implementation, feel free to bring it over to [codereview.se] to have it peer reviewed - that'll change from the worksheet stuff!

Comment: ummmm...... @TimWilliams? Why would a factory not be something you'd typically use in VBA? I use them *all the time* to get around the fact that there aren't any constructors. Also, they're an *absolute necessity* if you're writing code libraries in VBA.